# Do Moderators get paid?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I am just curious - do mods on this site get paid? What's the use if you (a moderator) are not getting paid? If you are indeed getting paid, can you elaborate on what's your salary?

Comment: They used to get hats and other garbage doled out from SE:HQ. Now they don't even get that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [No.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169205/278659)

Comment: In the immortal words of [some guy](http://atdyjtyk.blogspot.com/2019/04/thats-odd-coin-i-wonder-why-on-hold.html) "*While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page change*"

Comment: @Valorum You could try to [edit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) some more detail into this post, although you might see why not if you click the edit button.

Comment: You didn't get me. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rick-roll-detector/naiegljfmojjaphollbjobpedcdnkkfp/related?hl=en

Answer (score 11):

Moderators do not get paid, they are elected volunteer members of the community trusted with extra powers to help curate the site. I can’t speak for others clearly, and I am not a moderator myself, but people do it to help the site out, because they enjoy it and because they want the site to succeed.

The only people who get paid are Stack Exchange employees themselves who are not moderators but may have moderator abilities.

Comment: As a moderator I agree with this answer.

Answer (score 8):

From the [Moderator Agreement](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement)

> I acknowledge and agree that **I am an independent volunteer moderator** for one or more sites operated by Stack Exchange, Inc. and **I am not an employee, agent or representative** of Stack Exchange, Inc., and I have no authority to bind Stack Exchange, Inc. in any manner and I am solely responsible for my statements and actions. I attest that my statements and posts do not represent the views, opinions or actions of Stack Exchange, Inc.

Now a [volunteer](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/volunteer) is "A person who works for an organization without being paid".

So, **NO**, *but with sources*!